# "state snapshots" used by Hibernate for dirty checking

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am in reference to a book about java persistence and Hibernate.

(See: https://www.manning.com/books/java-persistence-with-hibernate-second-edition).

The book repeatedly mentions "*state snapshots*" - used amongst others for dirty-checking.

See:

> The persistence context cache never shrinks automatically. Keep the
>   size of your persistence context to the necessary minimum. Often, many
>   persistent instances in your context are there by accident—for
>   example, because you needed only a few items but queried for many.
>   Extremely large graphs can have a serious performance impact and
>   require significant memory for state snapshots. Check that your
>   queries return only data you need, and consider the following ways to
>   control Hibernate’s caching behavior.
>
> You can call EntityManager#detach(i) to evict a persistent instance
>   manually from the persistence context. You can call
>   EntityManager#clear() to detach all persistent entity instances,
>   leaving you with an empty persistence context.
>
> The native Session API has some extra operations you might find
>   useful. You can set the entire persistence context to read-only mode.
>   This disables state snapshots and dirty checking, and Hibernate won’t
>   write modifications to the database:
>
> `em.unwrap(Session.class).setDefaultReadOnly(true);`
>
> `Item item = em.find(Item.class, ITEM_ID);`
>
> `item.setName("New Name");`
>
> `em.flush();`

My questions therefore are:

- What is the difference between the **proxy objects** created by Hibernate from `@Entity` classes and the **state snapshots** referred to above?
- Where can I find further documentation about those **state snapshots**?

**edit**: Taking into account Naros's answer, I found very interesting information within the hibernate documentation for the Session class: `Session#setDefaultReadOnly`

> Change the default for entities and proxies loaded into this session
>   from modifiable to read-only mode, or from modifiable to read-only
>   mode. Read-only entities are not dirty-checked and snapshots of
>   persistent state are not maintained. Read-only entities can be
>   modified, but changes are not persisted. When a proxy is initialized,
>   the loaded entity will have the same read-only/modifiable setting as
>   the uninitialized proxy has, regardless of the session's current
>   setting. To change the read-only/modifiable setting for a particular
>   entity or proxy that is already in this session

Here is the link: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#setDefaultReadOnly-boolean-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is what they represent.  Any object loaded into the persistence  context is almost always loaded with some state snapshot, whether they may be an identifier or only the non-lazy loaded properties.

When an entity is loaded into the persistence context, the values of the entity's database columns will be stored in an object array that is referred to as *state snapshot*.  It represents the state of the entity at the database level that we can later use as the user changes the entity object's state throughout the lifecycle of a transaction, such as doing dirty checks.

On the other hand, a proxy represents a place holder that wraps an identifier.   It does maintain some state snapshot, typically the identifier, but it isn't the complete database row and therefore, dirty checking can't nor isn't performed on a proxy instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot Naros. Can you kindly point me to the relevant part of the documentation that mentions what you have explained or better still to the source code for the hibernate class responsible for managing state snapshots?

Comment: Hi again Naros. I have found the documentation and have edited my post accordingly. A link to the source code relevant to state snapshots would be great from you!!